# SQL insert command shows error if int type data is not typed

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-insert

I'm working with a local database, and I have written an insert command to add values to the database. The problem is that I have some int types, which I get as "+textBox1.text", without ' ', because there are numbers only.

But, if I left like this, and I don't type values in this textboxes, the query is wrong and shows error because some commas. Then, if I change their type to `nvarchar`, and get them as follow '"+textBox.Text"', it doesn't insert anything. So how can I keep them as `int`, and insert them properly? Thanks !

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO info(Nume, Prenume, Data, Proiect, Schimburi, Poza, Acord, Baza) 
      VALUES('" + numeTextBox.Text.Trim() + 
       "', '" + prenumeTextBox.Text.Trim() + "', '" + 
      dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "', '" + textBox1.Text.Trim()
      + "', " + label5.Text + " , @Poza, " + textBox2.Text + ", " + textBox3.Text + ");";
```

Comment: I suggest you using `string.Format` because this is unreadable as hell

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-parameterizing-your-sql-queries-the-right-way-to-query-a-database/

Answer (score 4):

You need to use named parameters for the command to autodetect the datatype:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO info(Nume, Prenume, Data, Proiect, Schimburi, Poza, Acord, Baza) 
      VALUES(@nume, @prenume, @data, @pro, @sch, @Poza, @aco, @schi);";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nume", numeTextBox.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prenume", prenumeTextBox.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", dateTimePicker1.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro", textBox1.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sch", label5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aco", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schi", textBox3.Text);
```

You can also specify the sql datatype by doing each parameter this way

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@schi", tSqlDbType.Varchar);
cmd.Parameters["@schi"].Value = textBox3.Text;
```

Comment: change **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());** to **cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", dateTimePicker1.Value);**

Comment: and  **dateTimePicker1.Value** ->  **dateTimePicker1.Value.HasValue ? (object) dateTimePicker1.Value : null;** :)

Comment: It is not inserting to db. And if I set their type from nvchar to int, it errors because the textbox is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the surrounding single quotes in:

`...oShortDateString() + "', '" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "', " + label5.T...`

convert it to:

`...oShortDateString() + "', " + textBox1.Text.Trim() + ", " + label5.T...`

for each int textBox

Comment: But they are like this and that's why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid concatenating values as string inside an sql query to prevent a possible [Sql Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack, use AddWithValue Method of SqlParameter. see [this MSDN Article.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

if you are reading integer value from a text field, you can convert these values to int using:

```
Convert.ToInt32(numeTextBox.Text.Trim())
```

But be careful to add both client side and server side validation for validating user's input.

Your code might look like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO info(Nume, Prenume, Data, Proiect, Schimburi, Poza, Acord, Baza) 
VALUES (@Nume, @Prenume, @Data, @Proiect, @Schimburi, @Poza, @Acord,@Baza)"

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nume", numeTextBox.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prenume", prenumeTextBox.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", dateTimePicker1.Value);
// And so on...
```